# opencv image processing without camera view in background service

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to create an app for image processing using opencv in android studio. I have no experience with Android Java coding. That's why I want to get a lot of advice. The current project is to receive the frame from the camera image in the service, not the mainactivity, and process the image. The problem here is that the background service must be capable of image processing. The current model is nexus 5. When you launch the app, the camera image appears. At this time, if home button or other app is executed, image data should be continuously input in the background and image processing should be possible. I've got a lot of search results now, and I've got the answer that surfacetexture can do it. However, no matter how you run other apps using surfacetexture, image processing using image data in background
 I do not know if I can make it possible. Below is my MainActivity and Service.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.TAG;

private Camera mCamera;
public static TextureView mTextureView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
    setContentView(mTextureView);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, VisionService.class));
}
}


public class VisionService extends Service implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private static final String TAG = VisionService.class.getName();

private WindowManager windowManager;
private Camera mCamera = null;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
private float[] mTransformMatrix;
public static Vibrator mVibrator;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    try {

        mTextureView = MainActivity.mTextureView;
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        Log.i("ABC","onCreate");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("ABC","onCreate exception "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed method");

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    VisionService getService() {
        // Return this instance of this service so clients can call public methods
        return VisionService.this;
    }
}//end inner class that returns an instance of the service.

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}//end onBind.

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    mCamera = Camera.open(1);
    if (mCamera == null) {
        // Seeing this on Nexus 7 2012 -- I guess it wants a rear-facing camera, but
        // there isn't one.  TODO: fix
        throw new RuntimeException("Default camera not available");

    }
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);

        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (data == null) return;
                Camera.Size size = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
                if (size == null) return;

                //This is where I start my thread that analyzes images
                Log.i("TAG","Hayoon");

            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Something bad happened
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

}
}
```

Comment: You need to process directly the camera preview or just the captured image ? Hard to understand what you ask :/

Comment: @JoachimHuet 
While i'm running another app, the app i want to create must be working. The app I want to create must continuously receive camera frames and be able to process images using opencv. However, when there is no frame preview, camera frames are not image processed. My answer is to create an app that can continue to process images in the background without the frame preview.